# Visual Studio - Corrupted .xaml file

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, xaml

Recently I've put my computer to sleep, and when I started it up, the computer turned off.

Before I open the file, it asks me about Encoding. I've tried multiple, and even the Auto-Detect. No luck.

Later when I turned it on, the MainWindow.**xaml** looked like this:

[image: Invalid Markup]

The MainWindow.**xaml.cs** is surprisingly fine, and even registers the variables written in the XAML file. Also other XAML files in project are fine.

When I hover over the lines, this error shows: `The value "□" is not a valid character`

Does anyone know if the MainWindow.xaml is salvageable or is it a lost cause?

Thank you a lot for your answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clear the shadow cache and restart visual studio. It should be fine.

Shadow cache is located at

```
C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\Designer\ShadowCache
```

Delete the shadow cache for corresponding visual studio version and restart it. It should be working fine.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However the XAML file is exactly the same as before, so unusable.

Comment: Did you check any other xaml file?
Or only this one is causing the issue?

Comment: Every other XAML file is completely fine. Even the corrupted file's .cs file works fine and even reads the variables correctly.

Comment: Oh then your entire file might have been corrupted. But that happens very rarely.  Normally this would do the work around in such cases.

Comment: @JakubLokša : Did you find any solution?

Comment: Unfortunately I didn't. I'll just start fresh. But thank you very much for your answer!

Comment: I am really sorry. Maybe the file got completely corrupted. Such cases never happened in my knowledge. Try using a versioning tool so that you don't lose unsaved data, if it's very important data. Sorry for being unable to help you out.